# Why Does ASP.NET Core 2 Web API Give 404 Error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

There was no problem until I added a new controller to my ASP.NET Core (v2.1) Web API. Now, all my controllers are giving 404 error. The last added controller is UsersController. I'm not sure if I've changed something else.

**UsersController.cs**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DatingApp.API.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace DatingApp.API.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IDatingRepository _repo;
        public UsersController(IDatingRepository repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers()
        {
            var users = await _repo.GetUsers();

            return Ok(users);
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser(int id)
        {
            var user = await _repo.GetUser(id);

            return Ok(user);
        }
    }
}
```

**launchSettings.json**

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "DatingApp.API": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, Seed seeder)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler(builder => {
                    builder.Run(async context => {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                        var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                        if(error != null)
                        {
                            context.Response.AddApplicationError(error.Error.Message);
                            await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message);
                        }
                    });
            //    app.UseHsts();
            });

            // app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            // seeder.SeedUsers();
            app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc(); 
            }
        }
```

I've tried to restart Kestrel web server until now. Did not work for me.

Comment: You must have changed something else, roll back your changes until it starts working again.

Comment: `I'm not sure if I've changed something else.` Can you check your git commit history to identify the change?

Comment: Instead of,
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"

I used
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"

and it's gone. I can't find anything to say.